# Disabling norms for all fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

The elasticsearch norms page indicates norms can be disabled on a field-by-field basis dynamically. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/norms.html

Is there a way to easily do this for all field at once dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way of doing these changes at once for **many** fields. The only thing I could propose is to write some script or use [Java API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/indices-put-mapping.html), which will disable norms for all needed fields.